# Batch script: copy and rename file

Tags: file, batch-file

I have many files in a folder, for example some of the file:

> - myfile.11-11.txt

I want to find this file, copy and rename it, i.e. I want get two files, for example:

> - myfile.11-11.txt
> - myfile.22-22.txt

I run:

```
copy .\*.11-11.txt .\*.22-22.txt
```

And I get:

> - myfile.11-11.txt
> - myfile.11-11.22-22.txt

How can I get the result below?

> - myfile.11-11.txt
> - myfile.22-22.txt

Comment: why can't you simply copy the file with `copy myfile.11-11.txt myfile.22-22.txt` ?

Comment: because, "myfile" part can be different and a lot of files

Comment: I see. you want to copy all the files that have the same `.11-11.txt` suffix and extension. See my answer below.

Comment: please edit your question. instead of begin with "I have a file in a folder" you should say "I have many files in a folder" and show some of the files.

Comment: Have you ever tried to search SO? there are tons of questions concerning copying/renaming/moving multiple files...

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate with the `FOR` command over all the files you select, and parse the obtained name using the funny `%%~` syntax. See `HELP FOR`. And try this

```
set src=11-11
set dest=22-22
set ext=txt
for %%a in (*.%src%.%ext%) do call :docp "%%a" "%%~na"
goto :eof

:docp
echo copy "%~1" "%~n2.%dest%.%ext%"
```

what this code does is for each file matching `*.11-11.txt` it extracts its name part `%~n` twice, first in the `FOR` loop and second in the `CALL`ed code. Efectively it's the same as removing the extension twice and getting to the root of the name without the `.txt` and without `.11-11`.

After testing, remove the `echo` command.

Answer (score -1):

```
set str=myfile
set newnum=22-22
copy *.11-11.txt %str%.%newnum%.txt
```

If you need to do some dynamic string creation then article about DOS string manipulation is here: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Comment: this will copy **all** files under the very same name.

Comment: We are not here for spoon feeding. Please use logic base on your need. We can suggest a way, cant come with you till your goal.